# Ajax google map show by entering latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to show google map using ajax by entering latitude and longitude?

onchange of latitude and longitude in the text field should show the google map by ajax call.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show some code. What have you tried? What is broken?

Comment: follow this link
[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38630/how-to-display-google-map-based-on-latitude-and-longitude][1] you will solve your issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps embed API with latitude and longitude as 'center' parameter. You can have this in an iframe and change the URL every time the text field changes.

For example - https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=46.414382,10.013988

Check here for more - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide